# compare two array of objects and perform if condition using foreach

Tags: javascript, reactjs, arrays

I am trying to compare two arrays of objects, after comparing I need to perform some conditions like if the item id matches in both the array.

After this I need to return nothing if it is false I need to return some value.

I am trying to achieve this by using foreach. The reason for using foreach is that I need to apply the condition and I need to return something.

I need to check each value in both arrays to apply the condition.

I tried with some map methods but some are returning a boolean and I couldn't apply the condition by using that. I got partial output by using foreach but looping the second array returns undefined.

I need to compare these two arrays and I need to find the items which have the same ID for these items I need to return null, for the items which are having different IDs I need to return some value. Hence I need to compare each element in the array of objects and need to apply the condition

Could anyone let me know what am I missing? Thanks in advance!

```
var result1 = [
    {id:1, name:'Sandra', type:'user', username:'sandra'},
    {id:2, name:'John', type:'admin', username:'johnny2'},
    {id:3, name:'Peter', type:'user', username:'pete'},
    {id:4, name:'Bobby', type:'user', username:'be_bob'}
];

var result2 = [
    {id:2, name:'John', email:'johnny@example.com'},
    {id:4, name:'Bobby', email:'bobby@example.com'}
];

result1.forEach((num1, index) => {

  // console.log(num1.id) //result coming as expected

  const num2 = result2[index];
  console.log("num2", num2.id)

  // console.log(num1.id, num2.id);//here I need to compare result 1 ID and result2 id of each element

});
```

Comment: Can you clear up what action you are looking to complete against these 2 arrays?

Comment: Or alternatively, the output your expect for the example you gave.

Comment: What happens with `index` == 2?

Comment: Are you wanting to know if the ids in result2 are also present in result1?

Comment: @Matt yes , if the ID's present then I need to do if condition.

Answer (score 3):

Not sure that you really have to use `Array#forEach`. Depending on what you need to return you can use other methods such as `Array#find` as in the demo below and return the `result1` element or a property of it or `null`.

```js
const result1 = [
        {id:1, name:'Sandra', type:'user', username:'sandra'},
        {id:2, name:'John', type:'admin', username:'johnny2'},
        {id:3, name:'Peter', type:'user', username:'pete'},
        {id:4, name:'Bobby', type:'user', username:'be_bob'}
    ],

    result2 = [
        {id:2, name:'John', email:'johnny@example.com'},
        {id:4, name:'Bobby', email:'bobby@example.com'}
    ],
    
    output = result1
        .map(({id}) => [id, result2.find(o => o.id === id) || null]);
        
console.log( output );
```

Answer (score 2):

You were probably getting an error because while you're iterating through `result1`, you'll eventually get to `index === 2`, and then `const num2 = result2[index]` is undefined, because `result2` doesn't have that many elements, and anything like `num2.id` will throw an error.

I'm not totally sure what you're trying to achieve, but it sounds like you want to iterate through the first array, and find a matching element in the second array, then do something with them if there is a match, otherwise do nothing.

```js
var result1 = [
    {id:1, name:'Sandra', type:'user', username:'sandra'},
    {id:2, name:'John', type:'admin', username:'johnny2'},
    {id:3, name:'Peter', type:'user', username:'pete'},
    {id:4, name:'Bobby', type:'user', username:'be_bob'}
];

var result2 = [
    {id:2, name:'John', email:'johnny@example.com'},
    {id:4, name:'Bobby', email:'bobby@example.com'}
];

const doSomethingWithMatches = (arr1, arr2) => {
  // Loop through each item in the first array
  arr1.forEach(item => {
    // Find an item in the second array with the same id
    const matchingItem = arr2.find(item2 => item2.id === item.id);

    // If there is a match, do something with them
    if (matchingItem) {
      console.log(item, matchingItem);
    }
  });
};

doSomethingWithMatches(result1, result2);
```

Answer (score 1):

you can filter by id, and same name. Then change the value.

```
const mergedResults = result1.map((result1Item) => {
const result2Item = result2.find((item) => item.id === result1Item.id);
  return {
    ...result1Item,
    ...result2Item,
  };
```

output like this:

```
[
  { id: 1, name: 'Sandra', type: 'user', username: 'sandra' },
  {
    id: 2,
    name: 'John',
    type: 'admin',
    username: 'johnny2',
    email: 'johnny@example.com'
  },
  { id: 3, name: 'Peter', type: 'user', username: 'pete' },
  {
    id: 4,
    name: 'Bobby',
    type: 'user',
    username: 'be_bob',
    email: 'bobby@example.com'
  }
]
```